# PHP Directory Looping - Styling

Tags: php, html, html-table, directory, glob

Half way through making a web application for a school, the application loops through a students home directory and displays their files on the website in PHP.

(It uses LDAP Bind to verify the user exists etc)

At the moment it loops through the files and outputs each one in a table (Here is the code)

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
  <td width="4%" height="38"><div align="center"><span class="style1"><span class="style2"><img src="_css/folder.png"></span></span></div></td>
            <td width="20%"><span class="style2"><a href="browse.php?path='.$enc.'">'.$name.'</a></span></td>
            <td width="16%"><span class="style2"></span></td>
             <td width="60%"><span class="style2"></span></td>
        </tr></table>
```

Ideally we would like it to be able to change view's etc just like Windows (That bit is easy, its creating the damm views that is the issue)

Id ideally like to create a thumbnail view, but ive tried using  for every folder inside a  so its a column, but it bunches them all up.

Is there something for Tables, like in C# (FlowTableOverflow or w/e) so that when the table gets full, it starts a new row

Any help would be appreciated

(Screenshot of what it looks like now, and what I would like it to look like)

[image: What it looks like now]
[image: A rough image of what I would like it to look like]

Comment: You might want to consider an Ajax solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209103/what-is-the-best-web-based-file-explorer

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CSS and some HTML modifications to your table.

If I understand correctly, each folder is in it's own table. So what you can do is to `float:left` each table containing a folder.

This will display the folders horizontally while staying within their containing element. Like this (using your code): http://jsfiddle.net/fy9Dh/

If you want the text to appear under the folder you will need to add another `<td>`. So your table will have two `<td>`s one containing the image and the other which contains the link. For example:

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="4%" height="38">
            <div align="center">
                <span class="style1"><span class="style2"><img src="_css/folder.png"></span></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%"><span class="style2"><a href="browse.php?path='.$enc.'">'.$name.'</a></span></td>
        <td width="16%"><span class="style2"></span></td>
        <td width="60%"><span class="style2"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the final product: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcAmP/

**One final note:** This really isn't the correct usage of HTML tables. Tables should be used for displaying data.